# Ionic has no errors on installation but does nothing upon execution

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

after installing ionic using directions from http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/

and typing ionic on the command line, nothing happened. No errors, no messages, nothing.

```
$ionic
$
```

using ubutu 14.04, node js installed

Comment: could you share output of the installation commands? maybe the answer is there..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite unusual!! 
It might be worth making sure that the prerequisites are installed correctly. Can you try the following:

```
node --version
npm --version
cordova --version
```

finally, if npm and cordova are in

```
ionic --version
```

Comment: thank you for giving me an idea on where the problem might originate, What I did was I updated everything - from node to ionic. Thank you! its working now

Answer (score 3):

I've seen odd things in ionic when using node 5 instead of node 4.  You may want to try switching to node 4.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to type "ionic serve" not "ionic" to run on the browser.

Comment: well with ionic only it will display ionic specific commands, my problem did not produce those commands, thanks for trying to answer my question, I found out the solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to find your node.js command prompt to execute ionic commands.

1. Go to your node.js directory, if you are not able to fine, search for "Node.js command prompt"
2. Open it and type "ionic -v"

You should be able to see ionic CLI version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are in the project folder. After installing ionic through the CLI (example ionic start your-app-name tabs) run ionic serve and ionic setup sass if you are planning to use sass. But most of the times it's because you are running ionic serve outside of the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

for latest version of ionic i,e 2.1.17 you must have npm of version 3.10.9 and node of version v7.2.0 and above. To check the version use command node -v and npm -v and ionic -v. Even having older version of ionic even when it is updated also causes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ionic -v` for checking if ionic is installed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime your npm doesn't installed in the correct path in Ubuntu/mac which leads 
to improper installation of ionic. Try to reinstall all the things like 
node, npm, cordova and ionic. This might solve the problem